# Date format value not updating from previous format to new format after update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

When I update a column from a table with a date format of MMM DD,YYYY to a new format. The format doesn't change to the desired format which is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Even when update different value like `GETDATE()`. The date will change but the format will remain the same.

Current value & format from column the type is varchar

DueDate

> Jun 27 2020 12:00AM

---

Desired format 
DueDate

> 2020-06-27 00:00:00.000

---

Update statement

```
update TableName
  set  
  DueDate =  CAST([DueDate] AS smalldatetime),     
  LastSyncDateTime = GETDATE()
where CaseGuid =  'DA2CE6A1-0394-463E-8E8D-962F3A24ADC8'
```

Comment: Thanks @DaleK , is it not possible to update the existing record to a new date format ? Like mentioned in the description.

Comment: @DaleK No. I can read the date in any desired format I want. But in this case I want to update the existing records to a different format .

Comment: Hi @DaleK. This is not correct that "Dates are not stored with a format". The fact is that Date like any other data type have a format. Even INT have a format on disk. I HIGHLY recommend to [read this post as example on what is the exact format of DATETIME2 on the disk](https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/162/) (This advanced post level 500 internals).

Comment: Good day @Menzi, It seems like you are confusing between Date displaying format and Date storing format. I have a post exactly on this topic with the name "Date displaying format, vs Date storing format". The short explanation is that what you mentioned is only a client side displaying format while SQL Server have specific format which is used for storing dates. You can insert dates to a table using different styles and present it on the client side using different style but it will always be stored the same from the "SQL Server point of view".

Comment: @Menzi, In order to solve your original needs, all that you needed to do is to provide the server the information on the style which you use in the client side (in the query). This is done by using explicit convert with the third parameter which is the STYLE. For example if you use in the client side Israeli format like dd/MM/yyyy then use CONVERT(DATE, '27/02/2021', 103). For more information on different STYLE you can check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: And this "`dates are not stored with a format. The format only exists when you read it. – Dale K `" is simply not correct, as I tried to explain @DaleK. Dates has specific format which is used to store them. Yes, dates are stored with a format! Otherwise how can the server read the information from the disk and "understand" it? Each data type have a format which is used to store the data. Anyhow, this is advance topic - the internals of the stored data on the disk is advanced topic.

Comment: @DaleK using the format before the cast sorted my issue. Thanks to everyone .

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge confusion between "Date **displaying** format" and "Date **storing** format". The VERY short explanation is that what you mentioned is only a client side **displaying** format, while SQL Server have specific format which is used for storing dates (remember that the server stores zero and one only).

You can insert dates to a table using different styles (the official name for the displaying format is STYLE), and you can present the dates in the client side using different style, but it will always be stored the same from the "SQL Server point of view" according to the DATE type which is used.

In order to solve your original needs, all that you needed to do is to provide the server the information about the style which you use in the client side (in the query). This is done by using explicit CONVERT with the third parameter, which is the STYLE.

For example if you use in the client side an Israeli format like dd/MM/yyyy, then you should use `CONVERT(DATE, '27/02/2021', 103)`.

For more information on different STYLEs you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

Note: If you want to display the dates in specific format which is not covered by the existing STYLEs then you can use the function FORMAT() in your query. This function is fully flexible to return the data in your specific format. Remember that this function returns the data as string and it will not be date anymore.

For example, let's say that I want to use the format: "Day:dd,Month:MM,Year:yyyy". So if the date is '27/02/2021' then I expect to get "Day:27,Month:02,Year:2021". In this case use below:

```
DECLARE @D DATE
SET @D = CONVERT(DATE, '27/02/2021', 103) -- convert string to date for storing 
select FORMAT(@D, 'Day:dd, Month:MM, Year:yyyy') -- convert date to string for displaying
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution use the format function

```
update TableName
  set  
  DueDate =  FORMAT (CAST([DueDate] AS smalldatetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
  LastSyncDateTime = GETDATE()
  where CaseGuid =  'DA2CE6A1-0394-463E-8E8D-962F3A24ADC8'
```

https://www.sqlshack.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-the-sql-format-function/

Comment: What is the data type of `DueDate`? This is pivotal to understanding what is going on here. If `DueDate` is `varchar`, you need to stop what you are doing right now and change it to a date data type. Do not store dates in string fields.

Comment: Hi @Menzi, Using this solution "`FORMAT (CAST([DueDate] AS smalldatetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`" make no sense in my personal opinion and not recommended for few reasons. (1) FORMAT Is fully flexible as I showed in my example, and there is probably no reason to use CAST inside the FORMAT while you can use FORMAT directly. (2) The STYLE which you asked for 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' is covered by the built-in CONVERT and therefore, as I recommended, I think you should use CONVERT instead of FORMAT. This style is 120 by the way. Check the link I added in my answer for more STYLEs.

Comment: As per the updated question `[DueDate]` is of type `varchar`, OP just wants to change formatting of the column.